# telnet x11 on REDHAT 7 (Gnome 3)

Tags: ssh, xorg, telnet

I have been trying for the last 2 weeks to get X11 apps working over telnet connection to the server. I am not concerned about the security as I run a VPN to the server location as well. I just need X11 working all the time as I open a lot of apps.
What I have done on remote machine:

```
export DISPLAY=host-ip-address:0.0
```

On my local machine:

```
xhost +remote-server-address
```

Then I also added the following to my `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

I restarted my computer. But that wasn't enough.
I also checked if 6000 is listening:

```
$ netstat -a --numeric-ports | grep 6000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:6000               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

This is where I ran out of options and would like some help. Any ideas why X11 is not working? I have tried `ssh -Xf` but it isn't for me. As I open and close X11 apps all the time. When I close the original app opened with ssh, I can't open any more apps. I have a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291529/ssh-f-rejects-subsequent-x11-apps-after-the-first-x11-app-is-closed) open for it, but I haven't received a response yet.

Edit: So I got a response and I tried it, but it didn't help.
I had to install `yum install iptables-services` to the get the iptables installed on my system.

Then I added the following in my `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

I even restarted the iptables service using `service iptables restart`. But that still didn't get it working. Any more ideas?

Edit 2: Output of my `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:x11 state NEW
```

Should I remove the REJECT line?

Comment: I assume you executed the 'xhost' command on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. I did. I edited the question.

Comment: See if you can reach the X port from your remote server (i.e. do telnet back to your own machine at port 6000). It could be a firewall rule (see `iptables -L`)

Comment: I am not able to telnet back to my own machine from the remote server. I also don't see port 6000 in the output of iptables. How can fix the firewall issue?

Comment: Firewalls normally block everything so if port 6000 doesn't show up that's to be expected. What's the default policy of your INPUT rule? If it is anything but "ACCEPT", then a firewall is active. Adding a firewall rule is system dependant, for Redhat you may try looking at /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

Comment: Can you help me how to open the port 6000? Also is there any security threat to it?

Comment: *sigh* If there were no iptables installed, there was no firewall to begin with. So you only complicated things. I'm running out of ideas of why it won't work.

Comment: lol. that is funny. so should I just remove iptables?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a port to your X server is not recommended, SSH really is a better option. Anyone that breaks into your remote server will then be able to open a program on your X server, capturing keypresses, viewing the screen, etc. So you must be able to trust your remote server.

Anyway, the following should work for CentOS 6, it may work on Redhat 7. The file you need to edit is `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (as root!). It should start out with something like this:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun May 11 18:20:27 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [237324:104418063]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [311602:113967214]
:FTP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
....
```

The exact content doesn't matter, what's important is that there are firewall rules. As you can see, port 22 and port 80 are opened, so add a line to open port 6000; as an added security measure only give access to your remote server:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6000 -s ip.of.remote.server/32 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Then restart your machine or reload the firewall rules (`service iptables restart`).

Comment: I don't have the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file. So doesn't that mean that currently I have all ports blocked? I should just create a new file. I want to clear the air that Redhat 7.2 is my desktop not the server.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge here stops then. But yes, the iptables should be on your desktop. Look around, maybe it's somewhere else.

Comment: do you know where to add the line you mentioned in your answer. I just posted the output of my iptables. should the new tcp be at the top?

Answer (score 0):

JvO is absolutely right about telnet: just don't. SSH is better in so many ways, not just security, but in handling forwarding and other bits.

NB: RHEL 7 uses firewalld, not iptables, by default.

try:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
```

to see your settings. The default ought to work.

And make sure:

```
grep -i X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

comes up 'yes.'

Try it out with:

```
ssh -Y remote-server-address
```

Then:

```
xclock
```

(if you have disabled IPv6, or if you want more details, see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225642/95470)